# how can I check a column value=NAN for a datetime row value being the first of the month?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

That was the clearest way I could of asked the question I do apologize. I have monthly data like this, with only the first of the month having a data point

```
city   time        value
London 2000-01-01  5
London 2000-01-02  nan
London 2000-01-03  nan
..
London 2000-01-31  nan
London 2000-02-01  nan
London 2000-02-02  nan
London 2000-02-01  nan
...
London 2000-02-31  nan
London 2000-03-01  3
London 2000-01-01  nan
..
```

I basically want to do this following statement in pandas form:

If value = nan for timestamps with day = 1, replace that first of the month value with -1. I am struggling with the python sub sectioning notation using a condition as a mask.

So from above I want my data to then look like

```
city   time        value
London 2000-01-01  5
London 2000-01-02  nan
London 2000-01-03  nan
..
London 2000-01-31  nan
London 2000-02-01  -1
London 2000-02-02  nan
London 2000-02-01  nan
...
London 2000-02-31  nan
London 2000-03-01  3
London 2000-01-01  nan
..
```

but it obviously continues and there are thousands of rows.

edit-

Below is what I am starting to attempt:
So I saw online that I can make a condition and then use df.loc(that condition) to subsection the data so something like

```
mask = (df.time.dt.day==1)
```

So I believe this subsections the times for day=1 but I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Hi, what were your attempts and where did they fail at (if at all)?

Comment: If you have some code already, do post it so we can help further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), [`Series.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) and [`Series.isna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html):

```
In [503]: import numpy as np

# Convert 'time' column into pandas datetime
In [499]: df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format='%Y-%m-%d')

In [504]: df['value'] = np.where(df['time'].dt.day.eq(1) & df['value'].isna(), -1, df['value'])

In [505]: df
Out[505]: 
     city       time  value
0  London 2000-01-01    5.0
1  London 2000-01-02    NaN
2  London 2000-01-03    NaN
3  London 2000-01-31    NaN
4  London 2000-02-01   -1.0
5  London 2000-02-02    NaN
6  London 2000-02-01   -1.0
7  London 2000-03-01    3.0
8  London 2000-01-01   -1.0
```

**OR** use [`df.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
In [499]: df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
In [510]: df.loc[df['time'].dt.day.eq(1) & df['value'].isna(), 'value'] = -1
```

Comment: This is great thanks. Now If I wanted to filter this with data from a certain year for example or data with a certain hour, i could simply add  df.loc[df['time'].dt.day.eq(1) & df.loc[df['time'].dt.year.eq(2015) & df['value'].isna(), 'value'] = -1   im assuming?

Comment: Yes exactly like that.

Comment: amazing, much simpler than I expected, done.